# Android MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-activity

**Hello,

I have two problems about java and android, Can you help me ?

My Errors:

method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
**

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    // get the pin number
    String parameterValue = "";
    // get the ip address
    String ipAddress = editTextIPAddress.getText().toString().trim();
    // get the port number
    String portNumber = editTextPortNumber.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: What about not creating the same method multiple times?

Comment: Hmmm.. How to make ?

Comment: You essentially wrote the same thing twice. Why?

Comment: Okey. I Understand. Thanks..

Comment: Method does not override method from its superclass about ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first error:
*method onCreate(Bundle) is already defined in class MainActivity*

This is because you have the method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

twice in your class. Each method signature may only be present once in a class.
Without going into much detail about method signatures, the easiest way to achieve that is to not have two methods with the same name.

As for the second error:
*method does not override or implement a method from a supertype*

The class `AppCompatActivity` does not define a method `onClick(View)`. I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you can prevent the problem by removing the `@Override`-annotation.

Comment: My Errors:

method does not override or implement a method from a supertype **

  @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

Comment: I updated my answer: Just remove the ```@Override```.
However, please try to be accurate in your question the next time about where each error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

So your code contains two "onCreate" methods. Just delete the second one

Comment: Hmm.... I did . Thanks